# Set Qt tooltip area constraints programmatically?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QWidget that has a tooltip set. The issue is, it's displayed on one huge line(the tooltip is quite large). I would like to put a constraint on the width of the tooltip, so it would be displayed on multiple smaller lines instead of a huge one. Is there a way to set this programmatically, in the C++ code?

Comment: Isn't rich text an option for you? Example: _First line<br>Second line<br>Third line_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt tool tip is HTML aware. You can design the tool tip using HTML tags

Here is a simple example

```
ui->pushButton->setToolTip(QString("<div style = 'background-color:yellow;float:left'> <p><b>test tool tip</p></div>"
                                   "<div> <img src=':/someImage.png'></div>"
                                   "<div style = 'background-color:red;float:left'> <p><b>test tool tip</p></div>"));
```

Comment: thanks, I also discovered another way - I can add newlines